# Priorities for each clause of a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to prioritize results in SQL Server 2008R2 but I'm failing to prioritize the ones I want first at the top. Eg: If I query on city, state and zip, and I have a zip code and it matches, I'd like the result to be at the top. If the zip doesn't match, but the city and state does, I'd like these in the middle, then if only the country matches, the result can be at the bottom

If I try to use LIKE in the order by expression, the query doesn't run. So far I have:

```
DECLARE @cityState nvarchar  = 'new york';
DECLARE @zip nvarchar  = '11204';

DECLARE @myposition geography;
SELECT * FROM ZipCodes  z
WHERE Zip LIKE @zip OR (City LIKE @cityState+'%' and State LIKE @cityState+'%' ) 
ORDER BY z.Zip LIKE @zip desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM ZipCodes  z
WHERE Zip LIKE @zip OR (City LIKE @cityState+'%' and State LIKE @cityState+'%' ) 
ORDER BY 
CASE
    WHEN z.Zip LIKE @zip THEN 1
    WHEN City LIKE @cityState+'%' and State LIKE @cityState+'%' THEN 2
    WHEN State LIKE @cityState+'%' THEN 3
    ELSE 4
END,
z.Zip,
City,
State
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Z.ZIP like @zip THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
```

EDIT: My answer was incomplete, as a result of not having read the question completely.  The answer from gpeche is better.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `UNION`:

```
DECLARE @cityState nvarchar  = 'new york';
DECLARE @zip nvarchar  = '11204';

DECLARE @myposition geography;
SELECT * 
FROM ZipCodes  z
WHERE Zip LIKE @zip

UNION

SELECT * 
FROM ZipCodes  z
City LIKE @cityState+'%' 

UNION

SELECT * 
FROM ZipCodes  z
City LIKE @cityState+'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @gpeche. I actually ended up doing a few things:

- Declaring lengths on the parameters
- Accounting for state abbrevations (NY vs New York)

Which resulted in:

```
 DECLARE @myposition geography;
 SELECT * FROM ZipCodes  z
 WHERE Zip = @zip OR (City LIKE '%'+@cityState+'%' and ((LEN(@cityState) > 2 AND State LIKE '%'+@cityState+'%' ) OR (State = @cityState))) 

 ORDER BY 
 CASE
    WHEN z.Zip = @zip THEN 1
    WHEN (City LIKE '%'+@cityState+'%' and ((LEN(@cityState) > 2 AND State LIKE '%'+@cityState+'%' ) OR (State = @cityState))) THEN 2
    WHEN State = @cityState+'%' THEN 3
    ELSE 4
 END,z.Zip,City,State
```